# How to remove author from sbc-template?

Tags: titles, templates, author

I need use the `sbc-template` template to submit without author information, but the template throws an error when I comment the `\author` command, and when I use `\author{}` a `¹` is printed below the title. Any suggestion on to solve this?

I am using the [`sbc-template`](https://pt.overleaf.com/latex/templates/sbc-conferences-template/blbxwjwzdngr):

```latex
\usepackage{sbc-template}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We'd need to know which template you are using and how you are using it. The best way for you to show that is with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik thanks for this hint. Added too a link to template used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra `¹` you say is placed by the template before the `\address` field, so I suppose you removed that too. The address field is preceded by `\inst{\instnum}`. To remove that you can redefine `\instnum` to be empty as well:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{sbc-template}

\title{Instructions for Authors of SBC Conferences\\ Papers and Abstracts}

\author{} % Clearing \author field
\address{} % Clearing \address field
\def\instnum{} % Making \instnum empty

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  This meta-paper describes the style to be used in articles and short papers
  for SBC conferences. For papers in English, you should add just an abstract
  while for the papers in Portuguese, we also ask for an abstract in
  Portuguese (``resumo''). In both cases, abstracts should not have more than
  10 lines and must be in the first page of the paper.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks again. This solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid moving the text below authors and affiliation (i.e., keep a blank space where they are), you can use `\phantom{}` at each line of authors and affiliation, then using `\def\instnum{}` to remove affiliation numbers.